# A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed (Windows 10 / Toast Notifications)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

The DLL I made throws this error every time I try and load it in JNI. I narrowed the problem down to the main file, something in there is causing this. I'm not sure if it's because the toast notifications, couldn't find anything about that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "wintoast\wintoastlib.h"
#include "jni\me_glorantq_aboe_chat_client_notification_WindowsToastNotifier.h"
#include "ToastHandler.h"

std::wstring toastLogoPath = nullptr;

std::wstring jniToWstring(JNIEnv* env, jstring& jString) {
    jboolean isCopy = true;
    const char* chars = env->GetStringUTFChars(jString, &isCopy);
    std::string str = std::string(chars);
    std::wstring wstr(str.length(), L' ');
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), wstr.begin());
    return wstr;
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_me_glorantq_aboe_chat_client_notification_WindowsToastNotifier_initialise(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jstring logoPath) {
    if (!WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->isCompatible()) {
        std::cerr << "WinToast is not compatible with this system!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->setAppName(L"A Bit of Everything");
    std::wstring aumi = WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->configureAUMI(L"me.glorantq", L"aboe", L"chat", L"win10");
    WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->setAppUserModelId(aumi);

    if (!WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->initialize()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialise WinToast!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Initialised WinToast!" << std::endl;
    }

    toastLogoPath = jniToWstring(env, logoPath);
    std::cout << "Set logo path to: " << toastLogoPath.c_str() << std::endl;

    return true;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_me_glorantq_aboe_chat_client_notification_WindowsToastNotifier_showNotificationNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jstring header, jstring message) {
    ToastHandler* handler = new ToastHandler;
    WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate toastTemplate = WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate(WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate::ImageAndText02);
    toastTemplate.setImagePath(toastLogoPath);
    toastTemplate.setTextField(jniToWstring(env, header), WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate::FirstLine);
    toastTemplate.setTextField(jniToWstring(env, message), WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate::SecondLine);

    if (!WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->showToast(toastTemplate, handler)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to show toast!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I remove everything from this file, everything works just fine, apart from the missing implementations of course.